# MySQL Should the connection shown in Workbench read “Local instance MySQL57” or “MySQL57”?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench, connection, mysql-5.7

Specific Question:  In a 2-3 week process of learning MySQL and attempting to get a Python stock info scrapping program to feed data into a MySQL schema (database, table) I’m having serious difficulties with connections.  Having been bitten by doing something wrong & having to re-install MySQL about 8 times now, I’m getting rightfully leery of just about everything in the installation process.  Thus this question:

**Is “Local instance MySQL” which shows up in the upper left corner of the first (black) MySQL Workbench screen the proper one to use to connect to the database?**

As a follow-up,

**What is the difference between the windows service MySQL57, the connection MySQL57, and Local instance MySQL57?**

During the very painful process of trying to get MySQL up and running, I think I've gotten further when with a fresh installation the first screen reads “MySQL57” as opposed to “Local instance …”

My setup parameters are pretty vanilla with the exception that I’m putting the MySQL program on my D: drive as opposed to the C: drive (an SSD reserved for the operating sys).

**System:** Windows 8 64bit on a Xeon Ivy Bridge processor, large SSD’s, large HD’s, mucho RAM, dual X-fired video cards, ASUS Sabertooth MB (self-built a yr ago)

**Software:** MySQL 5.7, complete installation except for module for Visual Basic and Python3 (running 2.7).  Attempting to use the above hardware as both a server & client.

Even though I did my first Fortran programming in 1964, and spent my career on Unix machines, please regard me as a newbie when it come to the jargon associated with databases and client/server communications.

Why am I asking this question?  My “down the road question” will be about getting data from Python into the MySQL table, but “first things first” --- I would like to get a nice clean installation that I can trust.

By the way, I’ve thoroughly scoured this site and many others but have not found any answers that fit my requirements; they’re either for a non-Windows environment, too full of jargon for me to understand, or too simplistic to be useful.

TIA, Doug

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems there's some confusion about certain terms. So let's have a look at each:

- MySQL is a server application that you can install and connect to via
  TCP/IP (on any platform), named pipes (on Windows) or sockets (on
  *nix like platforms). This server is totally independent and has no name or such for identification.
- A Windows service to run the MySQL server: this is just a helper to allow running the server when your machine starts up. A service is not strictly necessary to run a MySQL server but without it you would have to manually start/stop the server. You can create as many service entries for a server as you want, but usually it makes no sense to create more than one. Since there can be more than one server (each with an own service) on the box it is highly recommended to give the services speaking names (like MySQL57 for a 5.7 MySQL server, MySQL56 or a 5.6 server etc.).
- MySQL Workbench connections are entries that store parameters to connect to a MySQL server. They are not tied to a specific service in general (you can connect to a non-Windows server too), but might be associated with such a service if they are configured for a local server (on a Windows machine) and you want to be able to start/stop this server from within MySQL Workbench (see Administrator section). They use the service name to act on a particular service (you configure that in the Connection manager, System profile). On Windows MySQL Workbench attempts to find installed service (to help new users to get up and running quicker) when it is started and no connection is currently defined. It then automatically creates a connection for each service it found (it uses "mysql*" as pattern to search for services). You can retrigger this process by removing all connections and restart MySQL Workbench.

The created connnections (like the “Local instance MySQL”) appear as tile you can simply click to open that connection. Be aware that clicking on the rightmost 1/4 of the tile will open an information popup only, not open the connection as such.

Now to your question:

> What is the difference between the windows service MySQL57, the
>   connection MySQL57, and Local instance MySQL57?

I don't understand where you see a **connection** MySQL57. There's usually only a **service** MySQL57 and connection in MySQL Workbench to the server this service is for involved.

I'm also not sure why this is such a dreadful process for you. Especially for Windows a lot of effort has been put into an easy installation experience. The normal process should be like:

1. Download the MySQL Installer
2. Run the installer. Select a typical scenario from the presets or select the individual products you want to have installed, say, a MySQL server + MySQL Workbench.
3. The installer will download and install the selected components.
4. Configure your server (like giving it a proper service name, TCP/IP port etc.).
5. After finishing the installer you start MySQL Workbench and can immediately work with your new server (as described above MySQL Workbench picks up the service automatically).

Depending on your download speed this should be something like a 5 - 10 mins. process.

HTH

Comment: Mike ... Thanks you very much for the time you spent answering my question! You are absolutely correct ... the installation process, creating new schema, creating and populating new tables is a straightforward process that takes approx 15 min.  It's when I got to populating a MySQL table from Python that things unraveled, enough so that I thought it best to make sure every nut and bolt was stress tested so the plane wouldn't fall apart in mid-air (so to speak).  Ergo, that's why my questions sound pretty basic.  I'm cutting and pasting your answers - very clear ... see next comment. Doug

Comment: to continue.  I'm back trying to populate a table from Python.  I think I finally got a clean install with some steps I did on my own or from the many hrs, of research I've done.  1.  I stopped all MySQL* Windows services using  "net stop MySQL*"  then deleted all with  "sc delete MySQL*" in admin. cmd window.  2.  I saved the my.ini file.  3.  I uninstalled everything using the MySQL  builtin routines.  4.  I then deleted all remaining MySQL folders in \ProgramData, \Program Files, and C:\Users\...\AppData\Roaming\.  My subsequent reinstallation went very smoothly. (continued)

Comment: to continue,  The only item that caused me to question the process was when I saw the "Local instance MySQL57" connection box.  I was and am pretty sure that that box read just "MySQL57" during a previous "successful" installation.  Ergo ... the question which you so clearly addressed.  My present step is trying to get Python to successfully load a MySQL table.  Before I ask another question, I've found many apparently good references and have to try out the various approaches.  I can communicate with my table, but not in the right format.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

with due respect sir , `windows service mysql` is a service created by windows upon successful to help you start / stop mysql. You can use `Local Instance Mysql57` without a glitch, as that is `just a way of MySQL representing your local mysql instance in the workbench`.

Comment: thanks for your reply.  Your gave me the "courage" to continue with my re installation.  Further info can be found in my comments to Mike (see above) who obviously spent considerable time addressing the "meat" of my question.  Please continue with your answers ... it was also helpful.  Thanks, Doug

Comment: Anytime sir, it has been an  honour to be of some help